# How can I connect to a specific database using Java?

Tags: java, mysql, database, oracle

I need a java application that can export some data from a Oracle database and write it to a Excel file everyday. I am really new to JAVA so I am making this app step by step.

First to all I'm going to show the database schema (simplified version):

- GLOBAL (allocated in bar.domain.es)

  -DATABASE1:
              TABLE A
              TABLE B
              TABLE C

  -DATABASE2:
              TABLE 1
              TABLE 2

One part of my code is:

```
        //Loading the driver
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        System.out.println("Driver Loaded");

        //Connecting to Oracle Database
        java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, DBUSER, DBPASS);
        System.out.println("Connection Success");

        //Creating statement
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();

        //Creating the query string
        String query ="SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE2 WHERE DATE=150603 AND ID=238";

        // Creating the statement to execute the Query
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(query);
```

where DBURL is: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@bar.domain.es:1521:XE"

With this code I get the message Connection Success so my app is connected to the database schema. However, in this schema there are several databases with several tables on each so my problem comes when I try to launch the query. The program doesn't find TABLE2 which is a table of the DATABASE2. I think that I should specify in someway that I want to search this TABLE2 in DATABASE2 but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify in the query what database the table is in

```
String query ="SELECT count(*) FROM DATABASE2.TABLE2 WHERE DATE=150603 AND ID=238";
```